# On hosting project in Azure Cant able to get Backend data in Client side

Tags: c#, ajax, azure, azure-webapps

I have controller name "Products" in backend and when I will request data in the Client Side as:

```
var uri = 'api/products';
  $.getJSON(uri)
      .done(function (data) {
        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
        $.each(data, function (key, item) {
          // Add a list item for the product.
          $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#products'));
        });
      });
```

I'm calling it using an AJAX call and all works fine locally.
But when I publish it in azure its not working...
So friends kindly help me with this situation.

Comment: add what happens when you execute in azure in the description.

Comment: when running locally i will give path to the json file like "c://programfile/desktop/myjson.json" or  i will give the location of Debug/bin/myjson.json and my ajax request went to server side successfully and fetch data from json file but when i host it in azure the json reference show exceptionlike "Newtonsoft.serilize " exception